# Build failed on Mac OS not in Windows Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just moved to a Mac device, and a flutter project that can run on Windows 10, but when I try to go on the Macbook,

the debug console displays an error like this, please help, thank you.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: G:\\2. KoffieSoft\\Referensi\\fix\\Operasional\\mjw_operasional\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json

Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sir, I have found the solution. the solution I look for a file named G:\2. KoffieSoft\Reference\fix\Operational\mjw_operational\android\app\build\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\AssetManifest.json in the android file after that I deleted the file and I flutter clean => flutter pub get => run, the error no longer appears and my project can be run on a mac,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**2. KoffieSoft** -> This is okey for windows but problem on mac. Do not use space char on your folder names. You can use **_** like **2_KoffieSoft**

Comment: this location is G:\\2. KoffieSoft\\Reference\\fix\\Operational\\mjw_operational\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json i have on windows but i run it on mac with position on the desktop, why is the location that reads the location of windows?, it means I changed the location on windows first, then I moved it to the mac?